# Prefix the title tag, if IP address is the dev server

Tags: title, wp-head

I want to conditionally prefix the contents of the  tag if the IP address matches the dev server. I cobbled something together, and it will output the title tag correctly, but the original title tag precedes it, and therefore is the content shown in the browser tab. Thoughts?

```
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
if ($host =='0.0.0.0') {
    remove_action( 'wp_head', '_wp_render_title_tag', 1 );
    add_action( 'wp_head', '_wp_render_title_tag_dev', 1 );

        function _wp_render_title_tag_dev() {
            if ( did_action( 'wp_head' ) || doing_action( 'wp_head' ) ) {     
                echo '<title>DEV SRV:' . wp_get_document_title() . '</title>' . "\n";
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the filter? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_title/

Comment: @shanebp because when I work alone, I overthink and often overcomplicate things. Thanks. Solved.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @shanebp for reminding me to simplify

```
add_filter('wp_title', 'dev_srv_title');
function dev_srv_title($title) {
        $host = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
        if ($host =='0.0.0.0') {
                return 'DEV SRV: '.$title;
        }
    return $title;
}
```